# How to load array from web service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a static array like.Here it is static array.I want to load from web service.
e.g

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];

      tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto",
             @"Pig spit-roast", @"goat", @"beefed up beef", @"squidles",
             @"whale", @"crabbies", @"quack", @"Instant Noodle with Egg",
             @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork",
             @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake",
             @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

         }
```

I want to load all food from service like that

```
     NSString *soapMessage =[NSString stringWithFormat:

      @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"    
      xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"   
      xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
"<soap:Body>"
"<List xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
"<Foods></Foods>"

"</List>"
 "</soap:Body>"
"</soap:Envelope>"                            
];
```

Comment: There are two issues here.  Parsing the soap response and converting XML into an array of items.  Are you good with parsing the soap?

Comment: Yes I can parsing.Only I dont know load an array from web service

Comment: Do you want to use a third-party XML parser or Apple's XML parser?

Comment: tableData = [NSArray arrayWith what for load from web service ? I dont know this.

Comment: @bbarnhart I used xml parser for my project.But you don't understand me :) I said I dont know How I load an array from service. (e.g)  tableData = [NSArray arrayWith ?????? ];

Comment: e.g this code for load from html but I need load from soap NSURL *baseURL = [NSURLRLWithString:@"http://www.myhost.com/test.html"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];
NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);

Comment: You can not use `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url]` to parse the soap response.  You need to parse the soap response first to get your payload.  Then parse the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Use this XML parsing library : [TBXML](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)

and then follow this stepwise tutorial for parsing : [xml-parsing-using-tbxml](http://ioscoding.blogspot.in/2011/07/xml-parsing-using-tbxml.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You can parse this using TBXML. I have parsed SOAP using TBXML many times.

Comment: My problem is : I know load any labels,textfields from soap,I know soap parse but I dont know load an array from same soap service :)